# XML feeds from more than once source

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, sax

I'm new to Android and the Java programming language but I know what application I'm going to built. Just wondering how to build it.

I want to build an application which will use the internet to pull down XML feeds using SAXpaser. I have two major concerns:

- The XML tree is different on the websites i will use.
- I want to sort what XML content thats should be displayed in the UI.

What would be the best way to do it when using more sources? I dont ask for source codes, but more a suggestion on how to manage it all.

Should I use an external server to pull the XML and then the application could pull it from the server? 
Should i just build the hole thing inside the application? What tool would you suggest i use?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose everything is in place: network access, xml and xslt support, UI stuff and widgets (use xslt to transform the trees to a common form). Just start with one thing, e.g. fetching XML from the sources, and ask specific question from there.